# Maui How to show a list of strings in labels?

Tags: list, xaml, label, maui

I have an object *SearchResults* of the class *SearchPageResultViewModel* with a property *Highlights*  that is a list of strings. The number of list entries varies.
I want to display all the values in xaml.
The strings in the list have html tags, so I need to use labels with property TextType="Html" to display them properly.

**How can I iterate through the list in xaml and display the contents in labels?**

ViewModel:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels;

public partial class SearchPageResultViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   private ObservableCollection<SearchPageResultViewModel> _searchResults;
}
```

model:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels;

public partial class SearchPageResultViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<string> Highlights { get; set; } = new();
}
```

xaml:

```
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" >
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:SearchPageResultViewModel">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="auto, auto, *" ColumnDefinitions="Auto" >
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" >
                        <Label Text="(" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
                        <Label Text=")" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
            <!-- I'm looking for way to display the list Highlights.
                                           My pseudo code: -->
                    foreach(string highlight in Highlights)
                    {
                       <Label TextType="Html" Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="{Binding highlight}" />                        
                    }
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Comment: First, this is a Model. Not ViewModel. It is not for logic. It is for storing data. Second, Models should not be named after pages(Views). But after the type of data they store. Third, how do you plan to put a list into a single label? If it is really one label, value converter, or even easier - put one extra property that when GET is called to return your combined strings. If multiple labels are required - read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout

Answer (score 1):

Add the *StackLayout* width *BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ..}*

But there is still a problem with bound text including html tags. They are not displayed correctly. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13015
Should be fixed in .NET 8.

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:SearchPageResultViewModel">
            <Grid RowDefinitions="auto, auto, *" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Doname}" FontSize="30" />
                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Label Text="(" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
                    <Label Text=")" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Highlights}" 
                             Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label TextType="Html" Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```